# Display the current post author and his url in the post header

Tags: posts, theme-development, author, custom-header

I'm making some changes in my theme. I want that when they visit a Post the header should contain the post author and his URL.
right now I'm using this:

```
echo '<a href="'.get_author_posts_url().'">'.get_userdata($posts[0]->post_author)->data->display_name.'</a>;
```

the auhtor's display name is working correctly, but the link is going like

```
www.mysite.com/?auhtor=0
```

instead of this (for example)

```
www.mysite.com/?auhtor=36
```

so this is the code in the header

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/?author=0">Display name</a>
```

instead of this:

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/?author=36">Display name</a>
```

by the way: I'm doing this outside a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for anyone who's having this problem,this is the code I used:

```
 echo '<a href="'.get_author_posts_url(get_userdata($posts[0]->post_author)->data->ID).'">'.get_userdata($posts[0]->post_author)->data->display_name.'</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably calling it too early and the context for the current post is not filled yet. `get_author_posts_url()` accepts author's ID as first argument, You probably need to retrieve and pass that to it, similar to how you retrieve the info for following call.